# Apply change function for multiple selects with same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to apply change function for multiple selects with same class. What I want is when you select an option with same value as data-tab, content of that tab to be displayed. Also is it possible the first option with value=0 to be selected by default? My code works fine but only for the first group of selection.This is what I have so far:
https://codepen.io/tonyart/pen/VwwBzbP

```
<script>
$('.tab-content').hide();
$('#select-box').change(function () {
  var tab = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  $(".tab-content").removeClass("selected").hide();
  $('.tab-content[data-tab=' + tab + ']').addClass("selected").show(); 
});
</script>

<select id="select-box">
   <option>select year</option>
   <option value="0">2018</option>
   <option value="1">2017</option>
</select>
<div id="" class="tab-content" data-tab="0">
  content 2018 first
</div>
<div id="" class="tab-content" data-tab="1">
  content 2017 first
</div>
<select id="select-box">
   <option>select year</option>
   <option value="2">2018</option>
   <option value="3">2017</option>
</select>
<div id="" class="tab-content" data-tab="2">
  content 2018 second
</div>
<div id="" class="tab-content" data-tab="3">
  content 2017 second
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with the same `Id`, an Id must be unique.

So I've changed `<select id="select-box">` to `<select class="select-box">`

You can use this code:

```
$('.tab-content').hide();
$('.select-box').change(function() {
  var tab = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  $(this).nextAll(".tab-content").removeClass("selected").hide();
  $(this).nextAll('.tab-content[data-tab=' + tab + ']').addClass("selected").show();
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('.tab-content').hide();
$('.select-box').change(function() {
  var tab = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
  if ($.isNumeric(tab)) {
    $(this).nextAll(".tab-content").removeClass("selected").hide();
    $(this).nextAll('.tab-content[data-tab=' + tab + ']').addClass("selected").show();
  }
});

$('.select-box').trigger("change")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select-box">
  <option>select year</option>
  <option value="0" selected>2018</option>
  <option value="1">2017</option>
</select>
<div id="" class="tab-content" data-tab="0">
  content 2018 first
</div>
<div id="" class="tab-content" data-tab="1">
  content 2017 first
</div>
<select class="select-box">
  <option>select year</option>
  <option value="2">2018</option>
  <option value="3">2017</option>
</select>
<div id="" class="tab-content" data-tab="2">
  content 2018 second
</div>
<div id="" class="tab-content" data-tab="3">
  content 2017 second
</div>
```